# css - resize the gap or image based on container width

Tags: css, alignment, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a simple responsive image gallery with the default number of columns of 3. As the window width gets smaller, the number of columns should decrease as well (first to 2 and finally to 1).

The existing code works ok, but the moment the images get realigned to have 2 columns, they are aligned to the left, leaving an ugly space on the right hand side of the #container.

How would I dynamically increase the gap between the images so the images are still stretched across the #container keeping everything horizontally symmetrical within the #container? Could anyone help me with it.

I have tried a few obvious candidates (eg. #gallery img {align: center} but none of them worked.

The solution/hint could be css/sass and/or js.

```
<div id="container">
  <header><h1>My Gallery</h1></header>
  <div id="filter"></div>
  <div id="gallery">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="ggg" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="gog" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gallery" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gallery" />
</div> <!-- end of gallery-->
</div> <!-- end of container -->
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this code to CSS section

```
#gallery{ text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know text-align applies to images - works fine.

Comment: Pleasure helping you :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

Html:

```
  <div id="container">
      <header><h1>My Gallery</h1></header>
      <div id="filter"></div>
      <ul id="gallery">
         <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
         </li>
         <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
         </li>
         <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
         </li>
         <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Gal" />
         </li>
    </ul> <!-- end of gallery-->
    </div> <!-- end of container -->
```

Css:

```
    #container {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: gray;
      }
    #gallery{
      width:100%;
      list-style:none;
      clear:both;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }
#gallery:before,
#gallery:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    #gallery li{
       margin:0;
       width:23.3333%;
       height:auto;
       display:block;
       float:left;
    }
    #gallery li img{
       display:block;
       margin: 0 auto;
       width:100%;
       max-width:100%;
    }
```

Test on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGrgEq)

Comment: Thank you. Interesting, but it just decreases the size of images without reflowing them to 2 columns and then 1 column. The above would not be very usable on small screens as you'd see 3 very small images in a row, instead of 1 normal size image.

Comment: Just You are use: @media (min-width: *px){ - }